# Apache POI create groups of rows

Tags: java, excel, apache, scala, apache-poi

I found couple of example where we can read specific rows and columns based on Titles or row/column numbers but can we read rows or columns based on the tags ?

The idea here is I have different group of tests cases under same sheet and want to group tests cases by tagging one of the rows entries.

How can I retrieve those specific rows/cell values based on tags or some labels?

This answer is close to what I'm looking but not the exact one [How to read specific rows using Apache POI Event API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313716/how-to-read-specific-rows-using-apache-poi-event-api)

Comment: How would you apply "tags" in Excel? Do you mean "Comments"? Or "Names"?

Comment: Humm, I added a extra column at beginning of sheet and grouped my rows. added answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a extra column at beginning of sheet and grouped my rows. My scenarios are mapping to groups and all tests cases **TC02, TC03** are executed from it.

[image]

So I have created a method which will return `array[Int]` of indexes for that groups rows based on group names as below

```
 def groupOfRows(rowName: String, totalTestCases: Int): ArrayBuffer[Int] = {
      var rowArray = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
      var index = 0
    for (i <- 1 to totalTestCases) {
      var row = excelWorkSheetXlxs.getRow(i)
      index += 1
    if (row.getCell(0) != null && rowName.equalsIgnoreCase(row.getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim())){
        rowArray += index
    }
   }
    rowArray
 }
```